# OutOfMemory in Apache Lucene

Tags: apache, lucene, out-of-memory

I'm getting OutOfMemory error in Apache Lucene.

Here is the problem code:

```
DirectoryReader oldReader = directoryReader;
DirectoryReader newReader = DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(directoryReader);
if ((newReader != null) & (oldReader != newReader)) {
   directoryReader = newReader;
}
```

Here is the log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space
    at java.lang.Class.getMethodImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:917)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$MMapIndexInput$1.run(MMapDirectory.java:244)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$MMapIndexInput$1.run(MMapDirectory.java:241)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:327)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$MMapIndexInput.freeBuffer(MMapDirectory.java:241)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput.close(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:295)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:788)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:694)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:400)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.isCurrent(StandardDirectoryReader.java:349)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenNoWriter(StandardDirectoryReader.java:303)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:266)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:254)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:170)
```

Any idea, what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using MMapDirectory, you should be aware, that:

> NOTE: memory mapping uses up a portion of the virtual memory address
>   space in your process equal to the size of the file being mapped.
>   Before using this class, be sure your have plenty of virtual address
>   space, e.g. by using a 64 bit JRE, or a 32 bit JRE with indexes that
>   are guaranteed to fit within the address space. On 32 bit platforms
>   also consult MMapDirectory(Path, LockFactory, int) if you have
>   problems with mmap failing because of fragmented address space. If you
>   get an OutOfMemoryException, it is recommended to reduce the chunk
>   size, until it works.
>
> MMapDirectory uses memory-mapped IO when reading. This is a good
>   choice if you have plenty of virtual memory relative to your index
>   size, eg if you are running on a 64 bit JRE, or you are running on a
>   32 bit JRE but your index sizes are small enough to fit into the
>   virtual memory space

So, consider tuning your chunk size or choose other implementation of the Directory, like NIOFSDirectory or SimpleFSDirectory

Comment: I think since version 3.3 Apache Lucene uses MMapDirectory by default, which gives best performance as compared to the other two implementation sub-classes. I have not changed the default chunk size (1 GB for 64-bit JVM), so I'm not sure what should I do to tune the chunk size?

Comment: Do you think changing the ulimit to unlimited prevent the OOM error?